# Entity Framework database migration

Tags: entity-framework

I am working with sql server and entity framework in a web ASP.Net C# Project. I am working with "Database first" concept. This mean i draw my database structure from sql server management studio on my local development computer. I add fields, rename fields, add table, change type, etc in the life of my project.

What i want to do is to see what to do when i want to apply database structure changes on my production(s) server(s). Is there a way for entity framework to "detect" changes with a concept of migration versioning like in symphony doctrine ? I actually patch by hand by applying sql scripts on my production server.

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK the migration only works for code-first. If you want to change database schema the only way is to rebuild your Model classes.

Comment: don't you like to reverse engineering your `db first` to `code first` ?

Answer (score 0):

In all cases you need to do some development tasks

Depends on the entity framework model you are using,

1. Code first approach : then you can use the reverse engineering, you can find this extension online, you can use the *Tools > Extensions* and Updates to find it , or you can update your classes manually.
2. Model first approach: then right click inside the edmx and *Update Model from database*